# XCode and Simulator suddenly crashed and froze my Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode, xcode-simulator

I am using a MacBook Pro 13-inch 2020 (i5, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD) and using Xcode and Simulator to build my first app. However, when I run the Simulator, my MacBook freezes, and I can't do anything other than performing a hard restart (my project is very simple because I'm just learning Swift and SwiftUI). Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and how did you resolve it?

I've been using Xcode from version 13 up to the current version (14.3.1), and this issue continues to happen. Could it be that my MacBook is too old to build Swift projects?

[image: CPU]

[image: MEMORY]

Comment: What version of macOS is running on your MBP? The internal SSD is pretty small, relatively speaking (256Gb.) How much free space is on the SSD?

Comment: I'm using macOS Ventura 13.5.2, and about 77gb of SSD remaining. But it is the problem of SSD? 

Comment: No idea if it is the SSD, but sometimes very low free disk space causes inexplicable problems in macOS, although 77Gb seems good enough.